# Chrome 69 CSS Rendering Issue: columns, overflow, and position:relative

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

I recently ran into an issue with [Bootstrap's card columns](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/_card.scss#L256) **in Chrome 69 on Windows 10**. Namely, when combining `.card-columns` with `.list-group` and `.list-group-item`, then enabling overflow on the list group with `overflow: auto` and an arbitrary `max-height` value.

It gets more specific than that. A second card must be a sibling to the first card. Then, scrolling to the bottom of the first card renders the items un-interactable/un-clickable.

### Minimal Bootstrap example:

```css
/* obviously not showing Bootstrap styles */

.list-group {
   overflow: auto;
   max-height: 128px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="card-columns">
  
  <!-- Card 1 -->
  
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">Overflow Card 1</div>
    <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#">Item 1</a>
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#">Item 2</a>
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#">Item 3</a>
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#">Item 4</a>
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#">Item 5</a>
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#">Item 6</a>
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#">Item 7</a>
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#">Item 8</a>
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#">Item 9</a>
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#">Item 10</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <!-- Card 2 -->
  
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">Overflow Card 2</div>
    <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#">Item 1</a>
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#">Item 2</a>
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#">Item 3</a>
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#">Item 4</a>
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#">Item 5</a>
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#">Item 6</a>
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#">Item 7</a>
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#">Item 8</a>
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#">Item 9</a>
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#">Item 10</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Okay, still there? With all this in mind, I decided to eliminate Bootstrap styles one-by-one. Process of elimination. Perfect, I'm probably just doing something dumb.

### Minimal Native example:

```css
/* stripped down Bootstrap styles, plus styles from earlier */

body { font-family: sans-serif; padding: 1rem; }

.card-columns {
  column-count: 3;
}

.list-group {
  max-height: 256px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.list-group-item {
  /* problem style */
  position: relative;
  /* -------------*/
  
  display: block;
  padding: .75rem 1.25rem;
}

.list-group-item:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-columns">
  
  <!-- Card 1 -->
  
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">Overflow Card 1</div>
    <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#">Item 1</a>
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#">Item 2</a>
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#">Item 3</a>
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#">Item 4</a>
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#">Item 5</a>
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#">Item 6</a>
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#">Item 7</a>
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#">Item 8</a>
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#">Item 9</a>
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#">Item 10</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <!-- Card 2 -->
  
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">Overflow Card 2</div>
    <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#">Item 1</a>
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#">Item 2</a>
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#">Item 3</a>
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#">Item 4</a>
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#">Item 5</a>
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#">Item 6</a>
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#">Item 7</a>
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#">Item 8</a>
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#">Item 9</a>
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#">Item 10</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's where it gets fun. It comes down to removing `column-count` from `.card-columns` or removing `position` from `.list-group-item`. If you're in the correct environment, running the CodePen will prevent that `.list-group-item:hover` style being activated (following the rules above).

#### With all that said...

I'm not a fan of long SO questions. I rarely read them. So, hypocrite I am, I thought I'd tap the brains of you guys. **I'm fairly certain this is a Chrome bug.** This code works properly in both Firefox and Edge. (I couldn't seem to find anything with a quick search on the Chromium bug tracker and this seems like such a very edge case that there may be no point in moving forward with this.)

Oh, and resizing the page or double-tapping-to-select unusable list items must force some sort of redraw/layout because the issue isn't present after that. Agh.

I'm hoping you can either point out an existing bug report somewhere, a workaround for this issue, or proof that my computer is simply haunted.

Thanks for reading this far. Looking forward to your responses!

#### TL;DR

Combining `column-count`, `overflow:auto`, and `position:relative` makes Chrome 69 get spooky in October style. Send help.

#### Edit 1

My question was edited by community to favor SO snippets over a CodePen. In the SO snippet, resizing the page will not cause the lists to redraw as mentioned above. However, resizing the preview pane on [the original CodePen](https://codepen.io/shengslogar/pen/mzOrgm) will reproduce these results. Trivial, but worth mentioning.

#### Edit 2

Tested this morning on macOS Mojave. Issue is present in Chrome, but not in Firefox 62 or Safari 12. So it's not an issue isolated to webkit or Windows. I've resolved to carve pumpkins and avoid the position property altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is not present in Chrome 71 Canary on macOS. I'm going to assume this issue has been resolved and will be pushed out eventually.